# How can I check if an animation has ended in Vue Nativescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I found this solution for vuejs, but vue nativescript doesn' support v-on hook

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47634607/12937963

I'm currently assigning a class when an animation has to play:

Template

```
<Image
  ref="Image"
  :class="{scaleOut: scaleOutIsActive}"
  v-on:animationend="animend" //doesn't work
  v-on:transitionend="animend" //doesn't work
  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/05/Red_circle.svg/1200px-Red_circle.svg.png"
  stretch="none"
/>
```

CSS

```
.scaleOut {
    animation-name: kfOut;
    animation-duration: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes kfOut {
    from { transform: scale(1, 1); }
    to { transform: scale(1.1,1.1);}
}
```

This should trigger a function

```
 animend() {
      //do something
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you get callbacks for declarative animations in NativeScript.

You have to use imperative syntax to get full control over animation. Read more at [Animation Docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/animation-code)

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to SO!
Try adding an event listener to your image ref like this :

```
   let vm = this;
    this.$refs.Image.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
          vm .animend();
    })
```

example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    show: false,
    caughtEvent: false
  },
  mounted() {
   this.$refs.divtest.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
     console.log("transition end")
    })
   setTimeout(() => {
     this.show = true
    }, 3000)
  }
})
```

```css
.divtest {
    background: blue;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}

.divtest.loading {
    opacity: 1;
    background: red;
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out, background 1s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
   <div ref="divtest" class="divtest" :class="{'loading' : show}">Bye bye</div>
</div>
```

try specifying a more detailed ref for your image insteaf of *Image*

reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event

Comment: Thanks! And thank you for your detailed answer as well, though I don't seem to get it to work with nativescript vue. I expected it to work the same way since it also supports eventListeners.